# Ruby regex to split user and date text input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

i have user and date data combined in a string.  i tried splitting on ' ' (whitespace), but some of the users have spaces in their names.  i believe i have a working solution, but don't think it's best practice; i was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction.  i'm guessing there is a better way to implement some form of regex.  thanks.

```
def format_last_post(post)
  date_regex  = /\d+\/\d+\/\d{4}.*/
  date        = post.scan(date_regex).first
  user        = post.gsub(date,'')
  "#{date}\nby #{user}"
end

puts format_last_post("Professor Chaos 12/28/2014 1:18 PM")
puts
puts format_last_post("Big Bad Bill 2 12/14/2014 9:07 AM")

# OUTPUT 
# 12/28/2014 1:18 PM
# by Professor Chaos 
#
# 12/14/2014 9:07 AM
# by Big Bad Bill 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<User>.*?)(?<Date>\s+\d+\/\d+\/\d{4}.*$)
```

Instead of split you can use `match` to get waht you want.Just grab the captures or groups.See demo

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/6

Comment: thanks for the alternative solution.  what's the `?` at the end of the first capture do?  also for first capture, should i use `.+`, not `.*` if i expect there always to be a user?

Comment: i was also playing around with this solution, but noticed that it kept the space as part of the date match.  with the split, it got rid of the whitespace.  is there a way to do that with match/capture?

Comment: @JamieB https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/25 ??????? and yes you can use `.+`.The space has now been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Split your input string according to the space which exists just before to the date part.

```
> "Professor Chaos 12/28/2014 1:18 PM".split(/\s+(?=\d+\/\d+\/\d{4}\b)/)
=> ["Professor Chaos", "12/28/2014 1:18 PM"]
> "Big Bad Bill 2 12/14/2014 9:07 AM".split(/\s+(?=\d+\/\d+\/\d{4}\b)/)
=> ["Big Bad Bill 2", "12/14/2014 9:07 AM"]
```

In the above regex, instead of `\d+`, you could use `\d{1,2}`. Because the number of digits in month or day part won't exist more than 2.

Returned array or list index 0 contains the user part and the index 1 contains the date part.

Comment: thanks,i'm still new to regex. it looks like you used lookbehind to match the space just before the date part. what is the '\b' for?  is it necessary in this context?

Comment: `\b` means word boundary, which matches between a word character and a non-word character. I added just to make a correct match without the word boundary, it would match also `12/12/2000000000004`